# Windows 2012 fails to run powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-task-scheduler

Trying to get a script to run Under the task scheduler. I can run the following command from a powershell window with no problem

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File C:\DataProcessing\Scripts\MoveDailyOpra.ps1.
```

I created the task Under the Task scheduler and assigned it to run once a day. However, I see no evidence of the task even running. The ps1 file creates a log file so I can see whats happening but not even a log file is being created.

The task says it has run successfully.

1) How can I debug what the Task Scheduler is actually doing
2) What other attributes must I add to the task.

Comment: The question is going to be closed as offtopic unless you provide more details on the problem.

Comment: How is this supposed to be debugged? All you've posted is something that you say works. How are you invoking the script in the scheduler that's failing? How do you know it's failing? Are you seeing an error message? If so, post it. What are the contents of the smallest script that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have updated the entry now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following into the 'Program/script' field in a new action in `Task Scheduler`. A popup should appear about arguments, click Yes on this.

```
PowerShell.exe "& 'C:\DataProcessing\Scripts\MoveDailyOpra.ps1'" -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NonInteractive -NoProfile
```

This is passing a command string into Powershell.exe, then Powershell.exe is then exicuting that string, which in turn calls your script with the `&` operator; known as the call operator. So the call chain is `Task scheduler` >> `PowerShell.exe` >> Your script.ps1.

[& Call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) - 
         Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as
         the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in
         variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not
         parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters.

If that still fails check that you have the script path correct and that the account your running the task under has the correct permissions to access the script.

Comment: Excellent. That worked! The only thing is I don't understand why. Why does the ps1 job have to be added in the quotes ?

Comment: @ColinLarcombe I have updated my answer to explain, if this answers your question can you please accept the answer.